# Pass empty callback Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a component that takes callback as parameter. I only want to pass a callback to it if a certain condition is true. What can I pass to it that will fail the `Callback.HasDelegate` check

Something like

```
<EntityActionMenu  DeleteCallback="@(Item.Id == 0 ? null : EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Delete))"></EntityActionMenu>
```

or

```
<EntityActionMenu SaveCallback="@Save" DeleteCallback="@(Item.Id == 0 ? EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Task<null>) : EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Delete))" ></EntityActionMenu>
```

**Edit**

This the receiving component

```
@if (DeleteCallback.HasDelegate)
        {
            <MatButton Raised="true" OnClick="@(() => DeleteCallback.InvokeAsync(""))" Class="warn">Delete</MatButton>
        }

@code {

    [Parameter] public EventCallback DeleteCallback { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DeleteCallback.HasDelegate);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DeleteCallback.HasDelegate);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want use `HasDelegate` to determine whether to display a button or not then you must create an `EventCallback` with a `null` delegate. If you use `EventCallback.Empty` `HasDelegate` will return true.

I think something like this would work.

```
<EntityActionMenu SaveCallback="Save"
              DeleteCallback="@(item.ID == 0 ? new EventCallback(null, null) : 
              EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Delete))" />
```

As an alternative you could change your component to check if `DeleteCallback` is null rather than use `HasDelegate`. e.g.

```
@if (DeleteCallback is null)
{
    <MatButton Raised="true" OnClick="@(() => DeleteCallback.InvokeAsync(""))" Class="warn">Delete</MatButton>
}
```

This might make it easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the id in your callback method?

Assuming the following code in `EntityActionMenu`:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<int> DeleteCallback { get; set; }
```

You could then do:

```
<EntityActionMenu  DeleteCallback="@Delete"></EntityActionMenu>

@code {
   protected void Delete(int id)
   {
       if (id == 0) return;

       /* your code */ 
   }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid your solution is not going to compile at all.

Comment: your new solution may work, but why allow the EventCallback 'delegate' to be triggered at all. The issue is that the EventCallback's target is the parent component, which may be the component page, and thus the whole page may be re-rendered unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I always find it useful to provide alternative solutions especially when it is not clear how the OP is using the component. Then they can choose the best fit for them.

Comment: @ColinBacon The point was not to have the function do nothing but to have HasDelegate fail because there are other things happening depending on that condition. Thanks anyway!